Is there a way to add 3D points to a 3D point cloud?
I have a pointcloud from a laserscanner measurement of a car. My problem is I can not measure under the car. My idea is to take simpel assumption that the structure under the car is a plane. Is there a way to "simulate" and add points which decribe the floor of the car?
My only idea is to choose manually the lowest points from the front, back and sides of the car (exclude tires) and building a plane. From that plane the next step would be extrapolating points.

Sure, that's one way of doing it.
